# Does String(byte[]) create a deep copy of the byte array?

Tags: java, arrays, string

Or is it that it just gets a reference to it?

I have a byte array that gets re-written by an external library - is it safe to pass it into a String constructor, or should I create a clone first?

```
byte[] b = MagicLib.getData();
String s = new String(b);

// actually a pointer to previous memory, just with different data
b = MagicLib.getMoreData();
```

Comment: Yes, the byte (or char) array is copied.  This is necessary to insure that the String is immutable.

Comment: The standard implementation of String contains a reference to a `char[]` array containing the actual characters.  In some JVMs this `char[]` array may be shared between two String objects, but this sharing is invisible, and can only be detected (if then) via reflections.

Comment: @HotLicks: worth pointing out that reflection can also allow you to violate string immutability.

Comment: @nneonneo - Reflection allows you to do a lot of things you shouldn't do.

Comment: @HotLicks - thanks, this is a good example of why some small number of us, programmers and hardware designers, advocate capability based systems where you can arrange that the shared char[ ] array would be read only for reflection using the String instances (but still writeable to the memory manager).

Comment: @KrazyGlew - I can think of better justifications for capability architectures.  But they'll never happen (in any real sense) in my lifetime nor likely in yours.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `String` contains an array of `char`s, not `byte`s. Therefore, the `String` cannot share the `byte`'s storage.

Additionally, note that the `byte[]` will be decoded into characters according to the platform default charset (per the documentation on `String(byte[])`), which implies further that a decoded version of the `byte[]` array has to be separately constructed.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle Java it returns a new char[] depending on the decoding charset used

Answer (score 0):

Java `String`s are immutable, so the entire array has to be copied. Otherwise, you could change the contents of the `String` by modifying the `byte` array.